# How can I grey all outside a country border in Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: layers, tiles, mapbox-gl-js, openmaptiles

I have klokantech docker container for openmaptiles. Now I want take the KML of the country border and grey all outside the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting polygon is a difference of bounding box and the border polygon. This difference polygon you can hide. For making difference it's good to use the turfjs tool.

Links:

- http://turfjs.org/
- a Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/kmandov/cr2rav7v
- how mask a polygon https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/

Answer (score 4):

A solution may be to use a Leaflet plugin that inverts polygons, such as [Leaflet.snogylop](https://github.com/ebrelsford/Leaflet.snogylop). An [example](http://ebrelsford.github.io/Leaflet.snogylop/examples/polygon.html).

[image]

Comment: not bad! But I look for a solution for mapbox gl js.

Comment: Consider that Mapbox GL and Leaflet can be used together using [mapbox-gl-leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet).